# Is the Canadian in 'That's the Canadian in you' an adjective or a noun?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

**That's the Canadian in you.**

Is this Canadian a noun or an adjective? To clarify the fog, I asked 92 to 96 native speakers residing in the U.S. for the acceptability of the following three sentences. However, both 'English' and 'Englishman' were equally accepted. I thought if 'English' was accepted more, I was going to presume the 'Canadian' was an adjective with the ellipsis of personality or something, and that if 'Englishman' was accepted more, I was going to suppose it was a noun.

1. That's the English in you. [acceptance: 73.0%]
2. That's the Englishman in you. [72.8%]
3. (That's the Englishmen in you. [32.6%])

Comment: It depends on your interpretation. Even *English* can be thought of as a noun rather than an adjective—especially if the phrase is thought to be describing the language itself.

Comment: I meant the listener's personality. I mentioned that in the survey.

Comment: Well, with *Canadian*, it could mean *that's the personality of a native of Canada in you*. Which would be using it as a noun. Or it could mean *that's the Canadian type of personality in you*. Which would be using it as an adjective—or at least adjectivally, if you want to think of *Canadian* as an attributive noun (it's also a proper adjective, of course).

Comment: As with many country-derived nationality names, *Canadian* is already an adjective used as a noun.

Comment: *I am Canadian* (adjective) and *I am a Canadian* (noun). Both sentences are acceptable. But *that's the Canadian in you* doesn't explicitly translate into one or the other.

Comment: I don't really see the difference between 'that's the personality of a native of Canada in you' and 'that's the Canadian type of personality in you.' Would you be so good as to explain it? Some say Canadian in this case could be a residue of 'the Canadian personality.'

Comment: I think your survey is pretty conclusive evidence that it can be either. Even translating it into a different language (Danish) where the demonym and the nominalised adjective are always separate (demonym: _canadieren_, nominalised adjective: _det canadiske_), I find both equally acceptable and likely to occur.

Comment: That syntactic slot will only take a noun, as far as I can see - so for me, what the survey shows is that 73.0% of respondents will accept *English* as a noun meaning *that which is English*. The same thing happens in the phrase *the pretty's on the inside*. Not all adjectives permit this though - consider *that's the kindness in her* and ? *that's the kind in her*. The difference here, I would say, is that *kind* has another meaning as a noun.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Is there a possibility that perhaps 'personality or characteristics' dropped off, and the 'Canadian' remained?

Comment: I was told grammarians hated to think of ellipsis. Is that true?

Comment: Related ... I suppose they're metaphors ... are ' inside every man, there's a [little] boy / king / Jack [Nicklaus] / monster / beast / machine (jokily) / ... [waiting to get out]'. These I find very persuasive in the choosing of the nounal interpretation. But Canadians and Americans have it easier than Englishwomen and Scotsmen.

Comment: Hi, what do you refer 'it' to in 'Canadians and Americans have it easier ...'?

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, per this usage, "Canadian" is functioning as a noun and even further a proper noun of nationality meaning that the capitalization of Canadian is correct. As an adjective it would, in most circumstances, not be capitalized.

Comment: The adjective is capitalised too.